# Yammer Like Button Not Working... TypeError: yam.helper is undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror, yammer, social-media-like

I am using yammer's like button. I have tried every browser under the sun. They all have the same funcationality. First page load they will load the JS and the like button perfectly... However after the first page load any subciquent load of the like button throws the below error.

```
Error
TypeError: yam.helper is undefined
```

code as follows:

Javascript:

```
yam.connect.actionButton({
    container: '#like',
    network: 'gsk.com',
    action: 'like'
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="like"><p></p></div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like somebody is serial downvoting me... yawn

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
A couple pointers:

Register for a new app at
        https://www.yammer.com/client_applications

You'll need it for your data-app-id.

The Redirect URI in your new app needs to match
    the app's URL.

Make sure the container matches the div id in the code:

```
    <script>
    yam.connect.actionButton({
     container: "#embedded-like",
     network: "domain.com",
     action: "like"
    });
    </script>    
    <div id="embedded-like"></div>
```

Comment: This helped me, but the container must be before the script.